# Mongoose select record with subdocuments count less than X

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have nodejs/mongodb and mongoose setup. Everything is the last version.

I'm kinda "brand new" in NOSQL and trying to rewrite using NOSQL and mongoose ORM with such SQL query:

`select * from documents where count(select * from subdocuments where subdocuments.documentId = documents.id) = 5 order by documents.id desc limit 1`

In my case (nested collections) the main collection structure is:

```
   documents: [{
         _id: ObjectId
         subdocuments: [{
              _id: ObjectId
         }]
   }]
```

So I need only get last one object that has count subdocuments = 5 using `documents.findOne` mongoose function.

Is this possible to make all those aggregations with mongodb/mongoose? I can't find anything relevant to my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator to find documents with an array field has specified length:

```
await documents.findOne({ subdocuments: { $size: 5 } });
```

In your case, you want to get last document with `_id` in descending order so you can add sort option to `findOne()`:

```
await documents.findOne({ subdocuments: { $size: 5 } }, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } });
```

Or:

```
await documents.findOne({ subdocuments: { $size: 5 } }).sort({_id: -1});
```

To find document with subdocuments length less than 5, you can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator:

```
await documents.findOne({$where: 'this.subdocuments.length<5'}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } });
```

Comment: Looks awesome! Thank you. I can't believe it's so easy tho

Comment: One more thing - what about condition that $size < 5? Is it possible?

Comment: To do this, maybe you need to use `$where`, something like `{$where: 'this.subdocuments.length<5'}`. Let me know if it help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an operator called [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which allows you to use aggregation expressions within the query language. This comes in quite handy 
here where you would need aggregation operators in your find query.

Breaking down your query into chunks for understanding, let's take the check

```
subdocuments.documentId = documents.id
```

In mongo, this means iterating the subdocuments array searching for subdocuments which meet the above criteria and can be expressed as follows using 
[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
{
    '$filter': {
        'input': '$subdocuments',
        'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
    }
}
```

The count  bit is usually expressed with the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator so taking the result from the above, this query

```
count(select * from subdocuments where subdocuments.documentId = documents.id)
```

is translated into the expression

```
{
    '$size': {
        '$filter': {
            'input': '$subdocuments',
            'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the comparison operator [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) to satisfy the condition

```
where count(select * from subdocuments where subdocuments.documentId = documents.id) > 5
```

as

```
{
    '$gt': [
        { '$size': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$subdocuments',
                'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
            }
        } },
        5
    ]
}
```

For equality, it is trivial to show with [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)

```
{
    '$eq': [
        { '$size': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$subdocuments',
                'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
            }
        } },
        5
    ]
}
```

The above can then be used with the [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) query together with $expr as

```
db.collection.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
            { '$size': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$subdocuments',
                    'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
                }
            } },
            5
        ]
    }
})
```

Sorting and limiting follows using [`sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) and [`limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) cursor methods respectively

```
db.collection.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
            { '$size': {
                '$filter': {
                    'input': '$subdocuments',
                    'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
                }
            } },
            5
        ]
    }
}).sort({ '_id': -1 }).limit(1)
```

---

This query has an aggregation variant as well. With the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate), the expressions used in pipeline are similar.

The find part is done within a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline step:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$eq': [
                { '$size': {
                    '$filter': {
                        'input': '$subdocuments',
                        'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
                    }
                } },
                5
            ]
        }
    } }
])
```

Sorting and limiting are piped within [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) pipeline stages respectively

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$eq': [
                { '$size': {
                    '$filter': {
                        'input': '$subdocuments',
                        'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this._id', '$_id'] }
                    }
                } },
                5
            ]
        }
    } },
    { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } },
    { '$limit': 1 }
])
```